# Generating mapping information on existing database use Doctrine 2

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I've got Doctrine 2 set up on Zend Framework 1.10 and have all the autoloading set up correctly including all necessary config settings in the application.ini. What I need to do now (or so I believe) is to create my Entity classes with mapping information so that the entity manager can work with my database.

What I don't want to do is write the Entity classes by hand as this will take ages but I can't seem to work out what to do next. Does the command line tool have functionality to create the entities, proxies and all other necessary classes from an existing schema?

Comment: I've now managed to generate yaml mapping for my existing database and they are placed in APPLICATION_PATH "/data/yaml" Now when I try to use orm:generate-entities ..\library\Application\Entity expecting it to generate the entity classes from the yaml mappings, it fails with the message "No metadata Classes to process"

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out what caused the "No metadata classes" error?  I am able to generate mappings using YAML/XML as long as I don't use the "newDefaultAnnotationDriver" with PHP-based annotations.  It's driving me mad!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the reverse engineering tool of Doctrine http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering

But it also doesnt detect everything as noted in the reference.

Your best bet is to reverse engineer and filling the rest with manually IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Using the command line tool:

```
 ./bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database xml ./bin/tmp
```

This will generate your xml mappings. Then, ensure that when configuring Doctrine CLI tool you change the driver to the **`XmlDriver`**

```
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver(array(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/../bin/tmp'             
));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
```

My CLI configuration uses Zend_Application, so I'm usually changing this in my Bootstrap.

**Now** run

```
./bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities ./bin/tmp
```

The Xml Metadata Driver is required in order for `orm:generate-entities` to convert from xml to entities. If you use the Default Annotation Driver, it will convert entities in the annotation driver path to entities which is not what we want here.

Comment: For Zend 2 (well actually just another way) you'll need to update the vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php file and add the following before the last two lines:

`$driverImpl = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver(
  array('./bin/tmp'));`


`/* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */`

`$em = $application->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');`

`$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);`